# Why don't I see a path to etags in PATH when running Emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com/ from the OS X dock?

Tags: macos, path, emacs

This is a follow-up question to the one at "Is `/usr/bin/etags` severely out of date in Yosemite?"

The Emacs in question is from https://emacsformacosx.com/ (GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2014-10-20 on builder10-9.porkrind.org).

If I start Emacs from the dock, then I don't see in `PATH`:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec-x86_64-10_9
```

If I use the script described at https://emacsformacosx.com/tips then I do see the above entries in `PATH`. But even in this case, `/usr/bin` comes first in `PATH`.  To use the etags found in `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9`, I have to give it precedence in some manner. I typically want to run etags in a shell script that is started in the Emacs shell buffer.

Why don't I see these `PATH` entries when I start Emacs from the OS X dock (I am using OS X Yosemite)?

At `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` I read:

`Emacs.app` sticks `Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/{bin,libexec}` on the end of the `PATH` when it starts, so if we stick our own architecture dependent paths on the end of the `PATH` then they will override Emacs's paths while not affecting any user paths.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an OS X bug coupled with different undefined behavior in Ruby and Emacs.

The root cause is that when launching Emacs from Finder, OS X is passing the `PATH` environment variable to the process twice! I wrote a test case and submitted it to Apple's bug reporter (id 19801095). Here's my test case:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /tmp/test.app/Contents/MacOS/

cat > /tmp/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
\$stdout.reopen('/tmp/test.app.log', "w")
ENV.each_pair {|k,v| puts "#{k}=#{v}" if k == 'PATH' }
EOF
chmod +x /tmp/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test

launchctl setenv PATH "Extra PATH"
open -W /tmp/test.app
cat /tmp/test.app.log
launchctl unsetenv PATH
```

If you save that and then run it from the Terminal then it will print:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PATH=Extra PATH
```

This only happens on 10.10. 10.9 will only print one `PATH`.

So that is the root cause. What's actually happening? The Emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com uses a Ruby launcher script so that it can ship a binary that runs optimally on OS X installs from 10.6 to 10.10. [This launcher script](https://github.com/caldwell/build-emacs/blob/master/launch.rb) manipulates the `PATH`:

```
ENV['PATH'] += ':' + File.join(base_dir,     "bin-#{arch_version}") +
               ':' + File.join(base_dir, "libexec-#{arch_version}")
```

So `ENV['PATH']` only manipulates the *first* instance of `PATH` in the list. When Emacs launches, it only pays attention to the *last* instance of `PATH`. Which on is right? Well, POSIX [talks about this case in the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html):

> If more than one string in an environment of a process has the same name, the consequences are undefined.

That means that neither of these programs are technically in the wrong.

Ok, so why does it behave differently from Terminal? That's because *something* is filtering out the duplicate `PATH`s in the environment when you are running from Terminal. I suspect bash. But it could also be Terminal.app. Either way, there's only one `PATH` in the environment and so the Ruby launcher and Emacs communicate correctly.

So what's the solution then? I think the Ruby launcher needs to change to deal with this, since it appears to be the default behavior in 10.10. That's a shame, since it's just more cruft. Luckily (as you can see from the above test script), Ruby can get to *both* `PATH`s so it can filter out everything but the last instance which would make it work the same way Emacs works.

Edit: [There's now a bug report on the Emacs build project](https://github.com/caldwell/build-emacs/issues/39)

Edit: This is now fixed. Nightly builds after February 11th and releases beginning with 24.5 should work (24.5 is currently a pretest but should be released shortly).